# Date reading the wrong time zone

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have the following date function:

```
function fixDate($strDateTime) {
 $strFormat = 'M, j, Y';
    $strFormatTime = '\a\t g:ia';
    $intTimeStamp = strtotime($strDateTime);
    $strDate = date($strFormat, $intTimeStamp);
    $strTime = date($strFormatTime, $intTimeStamp);

    if($strDate == date($strFormat)) {
        return "Today " . $strTime;
    }
    elseif($strDate == date($strFormat, strtotime('yesterday'))) {
        return "Yesterday " . $strTime;
    }
    else {
        return " on " . $strDate . " " . $strTime;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if it is my date function that is causing this or the way my database is structured, but the date on my pages is reading AM when it is supposed to be PM. It is also reading US - Central time, when I need it to be US - Eastern time. I have the dates stored in phpmyadmin as the Date category.

How can I change the date so that is reads as US - Eastern time?

Comment: read this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: i'd recommend saving all dates as gmt, and converting to a particular timezone in the "view" layer.

Comment: So I would have to add this before my date function?...`date_default_timezone_set('America/Cleveland');` ? or would I put in New York? Both are Eastern time zones.

Comment: @KevinSeifert why is that? Also how can I tell what the dates are being saved as. When I `SHOW CREATE TABLE`  for my db table this is in, I get nothing showing how it is saving as.. I get this ` `date` datetime NOT NULL,`

Comment: If you need to do date math, or end up handling multiple timezones, it's useful to get everything in a common unit -- GMT.  For the database itself, unless you are doing date math at the database level, it won't matter what time zone the db is set at (if everything is normalized to the same GMT unit).  IIRC, typically most databases will read the operating system time zone, or env vars, which  is often GMT.

Comment: Also, daylight savings time can be a major pain when storing data in the local timezone :-)

Answer (score 1):

I always set the default time zone to GMT

```
# store all data internally as GMT:

#   local tz 1 \
#   local tz 2  + <-> webservice.php <-> gmt tz
#   local tz 2 /

date_default_timezone_set('Zulu');
if( ! defined( 'DATE_FORMAT' ) ) define ('DATE_FORMAT', 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Then render GMT to the local timezone in the "view" layer.  Local time zones are a major pain to deal with, especially with daylight savings time.  :-)

```
#####################################################
# TIME UTILS
#####################################################

# STORE ALL TIME DATA AS GMT, ALONG WITH THE ORIGINAL TIME ZONE


# format date string referencing one timezone to another timezone, eg
# 'Zulu' -> 'America/Chicago'
# internally, store all data as GMT,
# where each person has a different view of data
# NOTE: full datetime is require, because of dst
function datetime_convert( $datestr, $from, $to, $format = null ) {

    if ( ! $from ) {
        error_log( "no timezone 'from'" );
        return $datestr;
    }

    if ( ! $to ) {
        error_log( "no timezone 'to'" );
        return $datestr;
    }

    if ( ! $format ) {
        $format = DATE_FORMAT; # defined above
    }

    $date = date_parse( $datestr );
    #print_r( $date );

    $dtime = new DateTime();

    # input in $from timezone
    $dtime->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone($from));
    $dtime->setDate($date['year'],$date['month'],$date['day']);
    $dtime->setTime($date['hour'],$date['minute'],$date['second']);

    # output in $to timezone
    $dtime->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone($to));
    $newdatestr = $dtime->format($format);

    return $newdatestr;
}


# convert dates with a GMT offset to offset == 0
# 2012-01-20T15:52:22.000-05:00 -> 2012-01-20T20:52:22.000Z
function datetime_normalize( $datestr ) {
    $dtime = new DateTime( $datestr );
    $dtime->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Zulu'));
    $newdatestr = $dtime->format(DATE_FORMAT);
    return $newdatestr;
}

# convert a local time to GMT
function datetime_to_gmt( $datestr, $from, $format = null ) {
    return datetime_convert( $datestr, $from, 'Zulu', $format );
}

# convert a GMT time to local
function datetime_to_local( $datestr, $to, $format = null ) {
    return datetime_convert( $datestr, 'Zulu', $to, $format );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change,

```
function fixDate($strDateTime) {
$strFormat = 'M, j, Y';
```

to

```
function fixDate($strDateTime) {
$strFormat = 'M, j, Y';
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```

Comment: It is still displaying in central time.